# Append object to DOM, buffer events until next tick?

Tags: javascript, dom

Ran across this interview question (below). Can someone first explain the question and then answer it?

> Write a function that takes an object and appends it to the DOM,
>   making it so that events are buffered until the next tick? Explain why
>   this is useful?

Does "append an object to the DOM" mean append ANY object, like `{ name: "Bob", age: "30" }`, or just html objects, like `<p> or <form>` objects?

Comment: *Only* DOM objects may be added to the DOM - not JavaScript objects. I imagine by "next tick", the interviewer means to use `setTimeout` in some fashion. I'm uncertain what is meant by "events are buffered" as the events are triggerable as soon as the DOM elements are exposed in the Document.

Comment: I feel like there is some informations missing. Or maybe i just don't understand the question since it's not my native langage...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it meas apending a Element Objects to the DOM, because if you wan't to append a regular JavaScript object, you would append it to a DOM Element, and not directly to the DOM.